# Gun aiming based on position of mouse/finger

Tags: java, ios, rotation, 2d

I am making a pretty simple 2d game. I would like to have the character be able to hold a gun and it would aim where ever your cursor (or finger on iphone) is on the screen. I would also like the gun to be able to rotate depending on where your aiming to make the effect look better. It may be pretty difficult what I am exactly imaging of but heres an example of what I'm looking for http://www.kongregate.com/games/HotAirRaccoon/kids-vs-santa. I don't need any actual code, I would just need the logic to do this. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Check out these videos: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLW3Zl3wyJwWOpdhYedlD-yCB7WQoHf-My He implements all of the logic in C++ but no reason you shouldn't be able to implement it in Java. Look at Euler's angles and then Quaternions. This is basic game math stuff. Also this book should help: http://www.amazon.com/Math-Primer-Graphics-Development-Edition/dp/1568817231/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Comment: Thanks, the videos seems helpful, I'll go watch it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get the x and y coordinates of the mouse and you pass for movement. Different mouse events can be tracked using the logic of these coordinates:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            int dx = e.getX() - x;
            int dy = e.getY() - y;

            if (zrect.isHit(x, y)) {

                zrect.addX(dx);
                zrect.addY(dy);
                repaint();
            }

            if (zell.isHit(x, y)) {

                zell.addX(dx);
                zell.addY(dy);
                repaint();
            }

            x += dx;
            y += dy;
        }   
}
```